# Can you partition the HD of a G3 iMac for OS 9 and OS X?

Tags: hard-drive, imac, macos

I have an old Tangerine iMac G3 in nice condition, I installed a clean copy of OS 9 on it and I can run the "iMac Demo Summer 1998" interactive demo which is neat.

I'd like to install OS X (Tiger) on it.  (I know it will work because it was running Tiger when I got it.)

However, after installing OS X, I know the OS 9 interface will be gone for good, and I probably won't be able to run the old demo anymore.

My question is, can you partition the hard drive in the iMac so I have one OS 9 partition that is completely separate from the OS X partition, so I can startup which ever OS I want to show off to my geeky friends?

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. My old notes had me putting OS 9 on the first partition but I'm not sure if that's compulsory or just recommended.

Then in OS 9 you have control panel to choose your startup disk and in OS X you have a system preference.

In fact it's technically possible to have both OS 9 and OS X installed on the same partition. Install OS X first and then OS 9. You may find later versions of OS X will have trouble blessing the OS 9 folder if it is in the same partition but it certainly worked up till 10.4

Check out this old Apple tech note: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1732